# how to make sure clickable gets run not td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following css structure

```
<table class = "apps">
  <tr>
    <td>  
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

sometimes I have

```
<table class = "apps">
  <tr>
    <td>  
      <a href = "" class = "clickable"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have a jquery event on selector `td` and another on `clickable`.

How do I make sure that when 
       
is in a `td`

the clickable event not the td event gets run..

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to stop the event from bubbling using `e.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the event for 'clickable' call

```
event.stopPropogation()
```

Otherwise the event for the 'clickable' will be called, and then the event propogates to the .

You may also need to call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default action of opening the link with the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Selector can be

```
 $(td a.clickable)
```

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on a link inside td you are actually clicking on both: the link and td.  Since you have events for both elements, you will have to stop the propagation of events to the parent.  Try using event.stopPropagation() when handling your link event.